# IndexOutOfBoundsException for for-loop in Kotlin

Tags: java, list, arraylist, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

I have two lists in Kotlin, of the same size, `foodObjects: MutableList<ParseObject>?` and `checked: MutableList<Boolean>?`. I need to do a `for` loop and get the `objectId` from `foodObjects` every time that an element of `checked` is true. So it is this in Java:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < foodObjects.size(); i++) {
    // here
}
```

But in Kotlin, I don't know why, there are some problems. In fact, if I do this:

```kotlin
for (i in 0..foodObjects!!.size) {
    if (checked?.get(i) == true) {
        objectsId?.add(foodObjects.get(i).objectId)
    }
}
```

I've got `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't know why, it continues the loop also at `foodObjects.size`. I could do it also with `filter` and `map`:

```kotlin
(0..foodObjects!!.size)
    .filter { checked?.get(it) == true }
    .forEach { objectsId?.add(foodObjects.get(it).objectId) }
```

but I'm getting the same error. I use this to stop the error and get it to work:

```kotlin
for (i in  0..foodObjects!!.size) {
    if (i < foodObjects.size) {
        if (checked?.get(i) == true) {
            objectsId?.add(foodObjects.get(i).objectId)
        }
    }
}
```

Everyone could tell me why in Kotlin I need to do it, when in Java it works good?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ranges in Kotlin are inclusive, therefore `0..foodObjects!!.size` starts at `0` and ends at `foodObjects.size`, including both ends. This causes the exception when your loop attempts to index the list with its own size, which is one more than the largest valid index.

To create a range that doesn't include the upper bound (like your Java loop), you can use [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html):

```
for(i in 0 until foodObjects!!.size) {
    // ...
}
```

---

You could also clean your code up a bit if you did null checks on the collections you're using up front:

```
if (foodObjects != null && checked != null && objectsId != null) {
    for (i in 0 until foodObjects.size) {
        if (checked.get(i) == true) {
            objectsId.add(foodObjects.get(i).objectId)
        }
    }
}
else {
    // handle the case when one of the lists is null
}
```

And to get rid of having to handle indexes altogether, you can use the [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) property of a list (plus I use the indexing operator here instead of `get` calls):

```
for (i in foodObjects.indices) {
    if (checked[i]) {
        objectsId.add(foodObjects[i].objectId)
    }
}
```

You could also use [`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html):

```
foodObjects.forEachIndexed { i, foodObject ->
    if (checked[i]) {
        objectsId.add(foodObject.objectId)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've thought that it was similar to Java, now I've understood !

Comment: sorry for my question, but how to use this structure in a recyclerview? I've found the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is in regards to a RecyclerView, but you should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example from the Kotlin documentation for [ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html):

```
if (i in 1..10) { // equivalent of 1 <= i && i <= 10
    println(i)
}
```

As you can see

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

will be printed. So, the 10 is included.

The highest index of your collection `foodObjects` is `(foodObjects.size() - 1)` because it starts with 0.

So, to fix your problem, just do this:

```
for(i in  0..(foodObjects.size - 1)) { 
   // ...
}
```

A better way to write this would be:

```
for((i, element) in foodObjects.withIndex()){
   // do something with element
   println("The index is $i")
}
```

This way you have the element and the index at once and don't need to worry about ranges.

*I removed the null checks for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Here are various ways to ensure the index is valid:

```kotlin
if (index in myList.indices) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
// The rangeUntil operator (..<) is still exprimental in Kotlin 1.7.20
if (index in 0..<myList.size) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index in 0 until myList.size) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index in 0..myList.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index >= 0 && index <= myList.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
// Note: elements of the list should be non-null
if (myList.getOrNull(index) != null) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
// Note: elements of the list should be non-null
myList.getOrNull(index)?.let { element ->
  // index is valid; use the element
}
```